# How can I create a form from a list of models using WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a list of `Prediction` models. I want to bind them to a form and allow the use to post back. How can I structure my form so the post associates a Home/Away score with a `Prediction` model's `id` field for each item I bind to the form?

**view**

```
@app.route('/predictor/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def predictions():    
    user_id = g.user.id
    prediction= # retrieve prediction
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('A score is missing, please fill in all predictions')
            render_template('predictor.html', prediction=prediction, form=form)
        else:
            for pred in prediction:
                # store my prediction
            flash('Prediction added')
            return redirect(url_for("predictions"))    
    # display current predictions
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('predictor.html', prediction=prediction, form=form)
```

**form**

```
class PredictionForm(WTForm):
    id = fields.IntegerField(validators=[validators.required()], widget=HiddenInput())
    home_score = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])
    away_score = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])
```

**template**

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    <table>
        {% for pred in prediction %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{pred.id}}</td>
            <td>{{form.home_score(size=1)}}</td>
            <td>{{form.away_score(size=1)}}</td>               
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Predictions"></p>
   </form>
```

I am unable to get my data to bind correctly on `POST`. The required validators continually fail because the post data is missing all the *Required* fields.

Comment: Sure man. I can't really help you any further. Here is a working gist https://gist.github.com/nsfyn55/039288a4c1a6dd6ca8ee. There is either something you are not including or a typographical error.

Comment: I just copied the code you wrote and I get <ul id="predictions"></ul> maybe its something to do with versions?

Comment: perhaps I updated the gist for you to compare

Comment: Are you running my gist `python predictions.py` or are you trying to integrate it into your code. Cause that is what I am getting at you likely have some typographical error or other unrelated problem.

Comment: I just copied your code and ran it in my text editor..sublime text2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55144/discussion-between-nsfyn55-and-lorbat).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You need a subform that will bind to the items in a list of predictions:**

The form you have described will only allow you to submit a single prediction.  There seems to be a discrepancy because you bind an iterable of predictions and it would appear that you want a home and away prediction for each. In fact as it stands it will never post back an `id` field. This will always cause you to fail form validation. I think what you want is a list of subforms. Like so:

```py
# Flask's form inherits from wtforms.ext.SecureForm by default
# this is the WTForm base form. 
from wtforms import Form as WTForm

# Never render this form publicly because it won't have a csrf_token
class PredictionForm(WTForm):
    id = fields.IntegerField(validators=[validators.required()], widget=HiddenInput())
    home_score = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])
    away_score = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])

class PredictionListForm(Form):
    predictions = FieldList(FormField(PredictionForm))
```

Your view will need to return something along the lines of:

```py
predictions = # get your iterable of predictions from the database
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
data = {'predictions': predictions}
form = PredictionListForm(data=MultiDict(data))
    
return render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
```

Your form will need to change to something more like this:

```html
<form action='my-action' method='post'>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.predictions() }}
</form>
```

Now this will print a `<ul>` with an `<li>` per item because thats what FieldList does. I'll leave it up to you to style it and get it into a tabular form. It might be a bit tricky but its not impossible.

On POST a you will get a formdata dictionary with a home and away score for each prediction's `id`. You can then bind these predictions back into your *SQLAlchemy* model.

```
[{'id': 1, 'home': 7, 'away': 2}, {'id': 2, 'home': 3, 'away': 12}]
```

Comment: I get this error: UndefinedError: 'wtforms.ext.csrf.fields.CSRFTokenField object' has no attribute 'predictions'. My code for predictions in my view is:             predictions = Fixture_prediction.query.join(Fixture)\
                    .outerjoin(User,Fixture_prediction.user_id == User.id)\
                    .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==Fixture.id)\
                    .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id).all()

Comment: looks like its not able to find predictions()

Comment: would you need a for loop over the predictions?

Comment: I added the `hidden_tag` field back this is required if you have `CSRF_ENABLED` in Flask. This answer assumes that your model query works and returns a list of `Prediction` models with at least an `id` field. If that query isn't working its out of the scope of this question. Also remember in your `render_template` method `form` must be equal to an instance of `PredictionListForm` not `PredictionForm`

Comment: You don't need a loop `FieldList` iterates through each item and renders an `<li>` for each.

Comment: blerph! You might also have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649027/wtforms-csrf-flask-fieldlist. I have added in a fix

Comment: thanks for trying nsfyn55 although nothing is being displayed on my html page...its blank...I can't understand why my form is not showing..not even an error.

Comment: if i enter this in the template: {{ form.prediction.id }} it shows in my page "prediction" when I try other fields it doesnt show anything. That makes me think is prediction = or something up with the template.

Comment: Do 3 things for me and I'll help you. 1) do a little homework and narrow your problem to the most minimal example. I would expect you to narrow your `views.py` down to isolate your form render problem this means no POST or validation logic. 2) Spare me your database logic hand instantiate a few `Prediction` models and put them in a list that you supply to a `PredictionListForm` instance 3) Before you return put this print statement `print form.predictions()` and paste the result.

Comment: I want to see 3 things when you do this, Your `Prediction` model. Your  the two `forms` classes as you've written them, and your `view`.

Comment: I get <ul id="prediction"></ul>

Comment: Sure I'll put all that info above

Comment: please also include a stripped down jinja template that only has the most necessary markup(no styles, no ancillary tags, etc.).

Comment: Hi, how do you select a specific item from the tuple? Usually it would be like tup[0] but not sure how to get it to work with your suggestion when selecting in the template

Comment: That is a `namedtuple` is just a sample placeholder for your `Model` it behaves just like a class. `p = Prediction(id=1); print p.id`

Comment: So for this: data = {'predictions': predictions}
form = PredictionListForm(data=MultiDict(data)) you would go form.predictions.id?

Comment: @Lorbat this is not a help site its a Q/A site(Ask a question, get an answer). You can't keep appending things to this question. If you are stuck on something specific you should create another question, but do your homework and read this article http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/ or I'll have to downvote/close it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% for key in di_RAA %}
   <tr>
   <td><form id="Run" action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="TEST" name="RUN_{{key}}"> 
   </form></td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

It provide other simple solution for multiple button.
FieldList is good, it hard to get each button's name and trigger function.

Answer (score -3):

```
from wtforms import fields
from wtforms.fields import FieldList, FormField
from wtforms import validators
```

Some tips, It maybe add some import and clean the import error message.