# Flask Wtform calling both FieldList and FormField validate() causes error

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

so I have this code

```
class ItemPurchaseForm(wtforms.Form):
    purchase_price = IntegerField(label='Purchase Price: ',
                                  validators=[InputRequired()])

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not super().validate():
            self.purchase_price.errors += (super().errors,)
            return False
        #.... do other validations....

class PurchaseTransactionForm(Form):
    yyyy = IntegerField(label='Transaction Year',
                        validators=[InputRequired()])

    transaction_items = FieldList(FormField(ItemPurchaseForm),
                                  label='Purchased items',
                                  min_entries=1)
    submit_button = SubmitField(label='Add new purchase transaction')

    def validate(self, **kwargs):

        if not super().validate():
            self.yyyy.errors += (super().errors, 'super not validated')
            return False

         #.... do some other validation
```

As you can see there is a `FieldList(FormField(...))`, so I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649027/wtforms-csrf-flask-fieldlist) to fix previous error caused by CRSF field. And now if I have `def validate()` in `ItemPurchaseForm` it will give me error, and the error is just this: `{'transaction_items': [{}]}`.

If I remove the `def validate()` from `ItemPurhcaseForm`, everything works well. Is there any reason why that causes error? I did read this http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.validate, so does it mean that `ItemPurchaseForm` is a Subfield?

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem and have fixed the problem. I just forgot to put `return True` in `ItemPurchaseForm validate()`