# Dynamically adjusted forms inside FieldList

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask and Flask-WTF and I need to create a form that contains several blocks (subforms) of a similar structure (like a subform with one `SelectField` and one `TextAreaField`). As the [docs suggest](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList), I can use `FormField` together with `FieldList` to achieve this goal. However, I need to tweak my `SelectField`'s dynamically (changing their `choice`s at runtime according to values in the database). The docs now [suggest](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)

> Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices list to the field after instantiation.

One can find an example of this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375565/add-input-fields-dynamically-with-wtforms). However, `FormField` is accepting `form_class`, not an instance (at least, according to the docs), so it seems that these two recipes do not play well together.

Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it's easier than I thought. You have to create those subforms with empty choices, create list of them and then adjust choices inside the list items.

```
class UserForm(wtforms.Form):
# must inherit from wtforms.Form, not flask-WTForms'
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649027/wtforms-csrf-flask-fieldlist
    first_name = StringField('First Name', [validators.DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', [validators.DataRequired()])
    accepted_policy = BooleanField('Accept Policy')
    experience = SelectField('Experience', coerce=int)

class UsersForm(Form):
    users = FieldList(FormField(UserForm), min_entries=2)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():

    form = UsersForm(users=[{}, {}, {}])
    form.users[0].experience.choices=[(1, 'One'), (2, 'Two')]
    form.users[1].experience.choices = [(1, 'Uno'), (2, 'Du')]
    form.users[2].experience.choices = [(0, 'Zero')]
    return render_template("hello.html", form=form)
```

And here is a template:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}

<form method=post>
  <dl>
      {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
      {%  for user_entry_form in form.users %}
          {{ user_entry_form.name }}
    {{ render_field(user_entry_form.first_name) }}
    {{ render_field(user_entry_form.last_name) }}
    {{ render_field(user_entry_form.experience) }}
      {%  endfor %}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Go!>
</form>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, and I had to use something like `form.users.append_entry()` to get this to work.

Comment: Hi Jeff, i'm interested to know how you did that. Could you take a look at my question as I think your knoweldge may benefit me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959882/macro-and-javascript-function-adds-fields-to-wtform-but-data-in-new-fields-is-n